# Pyinstaller lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_proxy_steerable.cp39-win_amd64.pyd

Tags: python, pyinstaller, arcgis

I have written a Console application for generating ArcGIS feature reports and it's working perfectly while I tried it using pycharm virtual env. But when I tried to make an exe file using pyinstaller it's generating some warnings and the exe is not running.

Python version - 3.9
pyinstaller version - 4.3

- and I tried with both 4.2 & 4.3 versions of pyinstaller.

> 196881 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
> 199122 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython_poll.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199154 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython\message.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199183 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython_device.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199212 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython\socket.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199240 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython_proxy_steerable.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199300 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython\context.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199329 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython_version.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199352 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython\error.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 199380 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq-v141-mt-4_3_4-97a8c0cb.dll dependency of
> c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\emportal\venv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\c
> ython\utils.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
> 201783 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python39\python39.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the Arcgis module. SO I tried this with the cx-freeze and it worked. Successfully compiled my code without any issues.